# Very funny error on Xcode 8.0 beta 3 in accessing function from notifications and timers

Tags: ios, timer, notifications, swift3, xcode8

I am getting this very strange and rather mocking error from Xcode:
[image: Funny Error Message]
While executing:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(Booking.loadElement(_:)), name:String(format:"portal%d", portalIdent), object:nil)
```

And:

```
Timer(timeInterval:5, target:self, selector:#selector(Booking.bookingTimerMethod(_:)), userInfo:"load", repeats:false).fire()
```

As you see the compiler complaints the functions not to exist and suggest me to use the same functions!

What is this and how may I make up for it?

Comment: I can't see all of your code here, but do you have bookingTimerMethod set as a class func or a regular func.  Referencing it as Booking.bookingTimerMethod would require the method to be declared as a class func.

Comment: @jacobbullock The #selector statement is not that strict about whether you include the type name or not in my experience, even for instance methods.

Comment: @MatthewSeaman I think that is true that he wouldn't need to include the Booking reference if it was in the same class. But by adding it that way, i think it would be looking for a static (class) function not a standard func, which would throw an error.  though i haven't tested that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was simply due to the fact I forgot to add parameter 'notification:'.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(Booking.loadElement(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: String(format:"portal%d", portalIdent!)), object:nil)
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8 so far has some pretty wacky error messages that often don't lead to the problem, so let's ignore the messages for now.

Assuming your surrounding code has no errors (you should check because Xcode 8 beta often gives errors that are not descriptive of the actual problem), you need to make sure that the function you are creating a selector for is visible to Objective-C and not just Swift, since the APIs you are using are written in Objective-C.

`#selector` not only enforces that methods exist, but that they are visible to Objective-C.

To be visible to Objective-C, at least one (not all) of the following must be true:

- The type subclasses `NSObject` either directly or indirectly
- The method itself is written with the `@objc` attribute before it, especially if it is a private method.

If these are true, the methods clearly exist, and you've checked surrounding code thoroughly, [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com).

### An Alternative to Selectors

You can entirely avoid using selectors for `Timer` in the beta SDKs by using the new [swift-friendly `Timer` init](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimer/2091887-init) that takes a closure instead, and then call your function from there. his may however require you to design around not having `userInfo`.

Similarly, check out [this Swift-friendly `addObserver` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1411723-addobserver) on `NotificationCenter` that avoids selectors.